# Load runner is unable to launch IE8 while recording?

Tags: load-testing

I am using Win 7 Ultimate edition and i have installed Load Runner 9.10. I have added an exception to the firewall in order to allow vUser Generator. The problem is whenever I try to record a script (by clicking on start recording ) IE8 in not launched and recorder shows 0 events recording.
Here are few more details:

- Performing load testing on : HP tours (inbuilt sample site)
- Have I started the server for HP tours : Yes.
- Program (browser used for recording) : IE.
- Using default recording settings.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Load Runner 9.10 does not support windows 7 and IE8(even LR 9.50 is not completely supported on Win 7). If Windows 7 is your primary platform then you need to upgrade to Load Runner 11 otherwise use Windows XP. 
Here is a link if you need more details http://www.jds.net.au/tech-tips/loadrunner-in-windows-7/